# How can I convert AnnotatedData<SomeType!>! to SomeType

Tags: kotlin

I get this type mismatch error at the following kotlin code. I included only related code here.

How can I fix this error?

How can I convert `AnnotatedData<SomeType!>!` to `SomeType`

Thanks

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is AnnotatedData<LeaderboardsClient.LeaderboardScores!>! but LeaderboardsClient.LeaderboardScores was expected
```

```
...
import com.google.android.gms.games.LeaderboardsClient
import com.google.android.gms.games.leaderboard.LeaderboardScore
import com.google.android.gms.games.leaderboard.LeaderboardScoreBuffer
...
  private fun getLeaderboardData(leaderboardID: String, result: Result) {
    showLoginErrorIfNotLoggedIn(result)
    leaderboardsClient!!
      .loadTopScores(leaderboardID, 2, 0, 10)
      .addOnSuccessListener { scores ->
        val leaderboardScores: LeaderboardsClient.LeaderboardScores
        leaderboardScores = scores
        val out = "score"
        result.success(out)
      }.addOnFailureListener {
        result.error("error", "Unknown error", null)
      }
  }
...
```

Comment: It's hard to help without more information here. It seems that this `AnnotatedData` type comes from the library you're using (which provides `addOnSuccessListener`). You should check the properties of this `AnnotatedData` type, it probably gives access to the content of the correct type.

Comment: In fact, I've found a solution. I added to this question. Please check my solution if it is a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I am not sure if it is a decent one, because I am novice to kotlin. But it is working at least.

```
...
import com.google.android.gms.games.AnnotatedData
...
  private fun getLeaderboardData(leaderboardID: String, result: Result) {
    showLoginErrorIfNotLoggedIn(result)
    leaderboardsClient!!
      .loadTopScores(leaderboardID, 2, 0, 10)
      .addOnSuccessListener { scores ->
        val leaderboardScores: LeaderboardsClient.LeaderboardScores?
        val annotatedData: AnnotatedData<LeaderboardsClient.LeaderboardScores>
        annotatedData = scores
        leaderboardScores = annotatedData.get()
...
      }.addOnFailureListener {
        result.error("error", "Unknown error", null)
      }
  }
...
```